How to efficiently compute running geometric mean of a Numpy array?
Rolling arithmetic mean can simply be computed with Numpy's 'convolve' function, but how could I efficiently create an array of running geometric means of some array a and a given window size?
To give an example, for an array:
[0.5 , 2.0, 4.0]
and window size 2, (with window size decreasing at the edges)
I want to quickly generate the array:
[0.5, 1.0, 2.83, 4.0]

Do you need the decreasing size at the edges? This complicates things a lot. And am I correct that this means, e.g., for a window size of 3: The first window would have a size of 1, the second would have a size of 2, and the following ones would have a size of 3?

There may be scope to store the values, products of pair, products of products of pairs etc in cyclic buffers and combine them to get the overall product. You are still stuck with computing pow(product,1.0/N) or similar though. If you can restrict it to window size N=2^m then the sqrt() on modern hardware is astonishingly fast

How about switching to logarithmic space, computing an arithmetic mean and potentiating back into the original space? Also can we assume that the numbers are positive?

@simon No - that was just a way to make the question more specific but any reasonable handling of the edges (including only computing geo mean values when the whole window is filled and returning a smaller array) is fine.  For the decreasing windows - yes that is what I meant - and on the other side there would be 3,2,1

@ufghd34 Thanks for clarifying! I guess, my answer now covers the decreasing windows anyway :D See below

How big is the windows size in your real-world use-cases? How big are actually the arrays in practice too? sliding_window_view and convolve are not efficient for big windows.

import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
from scipy.stats import gmean

window = 2
a = [0.5, 2.0, 4.0]

padded = np.pad(a, window - 1, mode="constant", constant_values=np.nan)
windowed = sliding_window_view(padded, window)
result = gmean(windowed, axis=1, nan_policy="omit")
print(result)
# >>> [0.5        1.         2.82842712 4.        ]


Use the built-in gmean() from scipy.
Pad with nan, which, in combination with gmean(…, nan_policy="omit"), produces decreasing window sizes at the boundaries.
Use sliding_window_view() to create the running result.
Put everyting together (see above).

If you don't need the decreasing window sizes at the boundaries (this is referring to your comment), you can skip the padding step and choose the nan_policy that suits you best.
Update: Realizing that gmean() provides a weights argument, we can replace the nan padding with an equivalent weights array (1 for the actual values, 0 for the padded values), and then are free again to choose the nan_policy of our liking, even in the case of decreasing window sizes at the boundaries. This means, we could write:
padded = np.pad(a, window - 1, mode="constant", constant_values=1.)
windowed = sliding_window_view(padded, window)
weights = sliding_window_view(
    np.pad(np.ones_like(a), window - 1, mode="constant", constant_values=0.),
    window)
result = gmean(windowed, axis=1, weights=weights)

– which will produce exactly the same result as above. My gut feeling tells me that the original version is faster, but I did not do any speed tests.

You could simplify to gmean(swv(np.pad(a, N-1, mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan), N), axis=1, nan_policy='omit') ;)

Will gmean be more efficient than simple prod ?

@mozway Ooh, thanks! I was not aware of np.pad()! @YvesDaoust I guess this would need to be tested

There is no ideal solution.
You can use the cumprod function that computes the prefix products (all partial products from left to right), then take ratios of products that are one window apart and the k-th root.
E.g. a, b, c, d, f, e, g -> (a.b.c.d.e.f) / (a.b) = c.d.e.f
Unfortunately, for a large number of elements this can overflow the floating-point capacity.
Alternatively, take the logarithm of all elements, work with the cumsum and take the antilogarithm of the mean. But the logarithm is costly.
You can also form the product of the k first element, then iteratively multiply by the next and divide by the first.
E.g. a.b.c.d -> (a.b.c.d.e)/a = b.c.d.e
Unfortunately, truncation errors may build-up as the divisions will not exactly compensate the products.
If your window is short, the best option might still be prod on a sliding slice.

Zeros will also mess up the "multiply-then-divide' approach that works so nicely as "add-then-subtract" for arithmetic running means.

@Jaime: that's right. A workaround is to report null product when a zero is met, but skip multiplications and divisions with a zero term.

Fastest and easiest:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = [0.5 , 2.0, 4.0]
>>> pd.Series(a).rolling(2).gmean()[1:]
1    1.25
2    3.00
dtype: float64

Use:
pd.Series(a).rolling(window).mean()[window-1:]

This produces a rolling arithmetic mean (sum of values, divided by number of values n) rather than geometric mean (n-th root of product of values)

Oops! Thanks for correction

Replacing mean() by gmean() didn't work, it seems: with the latest pandas (2.2.2), this produces AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'gmean'
